# Python - Having some troubles with the super function and importing

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, inheritance

I have been trying to transition to Python recently but my brain isn't working well with it.

I really can't find what is the problem.

**window.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
```

**main.py**

```
from window import Window

win = Window()
win.mainloop()
```

Error message:

```
File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    win = Window()
  File "window.py", line 5, in __init__
    super(Window, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Am I just being dumb?

Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your code as posted works fine for me.

Comment: What............?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a recent python version super itself needs no arguments:

```
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Um... still doesn't work

Comment: Did the traceback/error change? What python version are you using?

Comment: Oops sorry I was using python 2. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry everybody ran the file with python 2.

Just typed "python3 main.py" rather than "python main.py"